# LTC3106 solar harvester example allows current flow into the solar cells

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, solar-cell

I'm trying to build a schematic that uses the LTC3106 which is a IC that can have both solar cells and batteries as inputs and gives a regulated voltage on the output.

The datasheet suggests a design for this purpose:

[image]

I've highlighted the part I found problematic. There are 4 reservoir capacitors connected in parallel to the solar cell. Given that the solar cells voltage levels depend on the light, under low light conditions the voltage could fall lower that what is on the capacitors. Couldn't that result in a scenario in which the current is flowing into the solar cells?

Note: I'm guessing a diode would fix the problem but would introduce at least a few hundred mV of voltage drop. Am thinking that perhaps I'm missing a pattern that could be related to the differences between the impedances of the cell and the IC input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the highlighted capacitors will discharge through the solar cell.

This will not harm the cell; for each event of darkening and assuming nothing else is discharging the capacitor, you'll just get that

$$\tfrac{1}{2}(110\,\mathrm{\mu F})(4.9\,\mathrm{V})^2 = 1.3\,\mathrm{mJ}$$

of energy dissipated in the cell (by way of the forward voltage drop of the solar cell considered as a diode), which is far less significant than the heating it will ordinarily experience by being exposed to sunlight.

---

If the solar panel were instead connected in parallel with your primary energy storage (say a battery or supercapacitor), this configuration would be unwise since the dark panel would in fact fully discharge it (whether or not the panel is also damaged by that current).

In *that* situation, a diode (or a FET switched by a controller, to avoid the voltage drop) should be placed in series with the solar panel to avoid the reverse current and discharging.

But this is not that situation, and your LTC3106 chip will presumably be doing the right thing with its two power inputs.